# Best practice for initializing Winsock in a networking library

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, network-programming, winsock2

I'm writing a small library that internally does some networking using the OS socket API.

On Windows it is required to initialize the Winsock by calling `WSAStartup` at the beginning and `WSACleanup` at the end. However [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsastartup) says it is allowed to initialize Winsock multiple times and then cleanup same number of times, because it uses reference counting internally.

And now i'm solving a dilema. What is a better practice for library writers?

1. Provide global functions `initializeLibrary`/`terminateLibrary` that calls the `WSAStartup`/`WSACleanup` and instruct the user to call them at the beginning/end of his application.
2. Call the `WSAStartup`/`WSACleanup` internally in constructors/destructors of my classes and don't bother user about it at all.

Now i see the second option looks more convenient, but is it a good idea? Aren't there any hidden bad consequences of doing it? Can it have performance impact? Is it a good practice for a library to do this secretly?

Comment: *Can it have performance impact?* -- What would you think reference counting prevents?  Also, how do libraries like boost::asio handle this?

Comment: Well yes, but it will still probably lock some mutexes, because it wants to be thread-safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it a good practice for a library to do this secretly?

I may be missing the point here, but to me the point of **any** library is to abstract the details away from the end-user, making using it hassle-free. Of course, abstraction may somewhat limit flexibility, but I don't feel like this is the case here. Note, that I'm only addressing the 'secrecy' issue, I honestly don't know how it affects e. g. performance.

> What is a better practice for library writers?

You're missing the third option here. I am generally against `init()` and `finalize()` functions, as it goes against RAII - users may simply forget to call those. However, you could design a 'token' class, created only at the 'root' of the application, that is required to make use of any other parts of the API. Consider this:

```
#include <WinSock2.h>

class ApiKey {
public:
    ApiKey() {
        auto wsadata = WSADATA();
        auto startupResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsadata);
        // ...
    }

    ~ApiKey() {
        auto cleanupResult = WSACleanup();
        // ...
    }
};

class Socket {
public:
    Socket(ApiKey& key) {
    }
    // ...
};
```

I'm not a boost::asio user, but as far as I know, that's how they do it. The `io_context` class serves as the `ApiKey`.

You can look it up in their source code if you want some more info:

https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/develop/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/winsock_init.ipp

https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/develop/include/boost/asio/io_context.hpp

Comment: Hm, context object. Not a bad idea actually.